# Iterate generator in tuples in python

Tags: python, generator, lazy-evaluation

Suppose I have a list

```
xs = [0,1,2,3]
[some_function(current, next) for current, next in zip(xs, xs[1:])]
```

I want to iterate over pairs (current, next) of this list. To clarify zip creates list [(0,1), (1,2), (2,3)]

The problem is that if xs is a generator instead of list to achieve this with zip I would need to create a list from it and it is surely not the optimal solution.

Comment: Despite the fact the proposed dupe says its input is a list, and this says the input *isn't* a list, the answer using `itertools.tee` is the same.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`itertools.tee(iterable, n=2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) which creates multiple independent iterators from one iterator.

```
my_iter, next_iter = tee(myiter)
next(nextiter)

[some_function(current, ne) for current, ne in zip(myiter, nextiter)]
```

Comment: Neat, I didn't know that existed

Answer (score 1):

This would work in case of infinite iterators etc.

```
def pairwise(iterator):
    """Iterate over pairs of an iterator."""
    last = next(iterator)
    while True:
        this = next(iterator)
        yield last, this
        last = this
```

Comment: I thought about that, but this will be slightly more complicated if you need itertate in triples, tuple of size n etc.

Comment: @user1685095 Then you could use a `deque` with `maxsize` set to n. But just use the other answer, I didn't know about `itertools.tee`.

Answer (score -3):

You can first transform the iterator into a list (if you are sure iterator can't be infinite):

```
xs = list(xs)
[some_function(current, next) for current, next in zip(xs, xs[1:])]
```

Comment: That might work in this case, but what about infinite iterators?

Comment: He said that he knew that he could do that.  He said _it is surely not the optimal solution._